# converting letters to special letters

Tags: php, string

i want to make function to change letters to special letters like

i made this code

```
$text = "hello my name is karl";
$my_array = array('н̈̈','σ̈̈','м̈̈','ӵ̈','ӥ̈','ɑ̈̈','ǝ̈̈','ı̈̈','ƨ̈̈','к̈̈','ɑ̈̈','я','l̈̈');

for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($text); $i < $len; $i++) {     
    $random = @array_rand($text[$i]);  # one random array element number
    $get_it = $my_array[$random];    # get the letter from the array
    echo $get_it;
 }
```

it should be ( н̈̈ǝ̈̈l̈̈l̈̈σ̈̈ м̈̈ӵ̈ ӥ̈ɑ̈̈м̈̈ǝ̈̈ ı̈̈ƨ̈̈ к̈̈ɑ̈̈я̈̈l̈̈ ) after i print.

the above code not working. so please help to me correct it.

regards

Comment: I don't see any association logic in your code between é and e.

`$random = @array_rand($text[$i]);`  $text is not an array it's a string, and even if it was $text[$i] would return a single element, so array_rand wouldn't work. Also, why are you using @? It'll just hide your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Look at this function.

```
$s = array('e', 'something else to search for');
$r = array('é', 'something to replace "something else to search for" with');

$stringy = str_replace($s, $r, $string);
```

PHP has functions for everything :P

Edit:

```
$search = array('h', 'a', 'm', 'e??', 'n', 'a', 'e?', 'i', 'z', 'k', 'a', 'r', 'l');
$replace = array('н̈̈','σ̈̈','м̈̈','ӵ̈','ӥ̈','ɑ̈̈','ǝ̈̈','ı̈̈','ƨ̈̈','к̈̈','ɑ̈̈','я'̈̈,'l̈̈');

$newString = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: Yes just do this, in $s put the characters you want to replace (Ex you want to replace 'e' with an accented 'e'. So put the accented 'e' in the same index of '$r' as you do the regular e in '$s'. I'll update my answer specifically for what you just posted.

Comment: I didn't know what half of the letters were meant to be, sorry, but I think the new example should be enough to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php and an array containing your characters you can easily do this

```
$yourtext = "hello my name is karl"; //Place your text in this

//Match your characters that you'de like to replace
$after    = array('н̈̈','σ̈̈','м̈̈','ӵ̈','ӥ̈','ɑ̈̈','ǝ̈̈','ı̈̈','ƨ̈̈','к̈̈','я','l̈̈');
$before   = array('h','o','m','y','n','a','e','i','s','k','r','l');

$yourtext = str_replace ( $before , $after , $yourtext, $replacing);

echo $yourtext; //prints  н̈̈ǝ̈̈l̈̈l̈̈σ̈̈ м̈̈ӵ̈ ӥ̈ɑ̈̈м̈̈ǝ̈̈ ı̈̈ƨ̈̈ к̈̈ɑ̈̈я̈̈l̈̈
```